# Обработка изображений в Python. Фильтр среднего значения (Image Blurring: Averaging)

Tags: python, обработка-изображений, фильтр

Нужно написать программу которая с помощью фильтра среднего значения размывает изображение с сеткой 3х3, 5х5. Проблема в том, чтобы не использовать cv2.blur

Вот пример кода рабочего приложения ([изображение что используется в нем](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSZ2B.png)):

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

bgr_image = cv2.imread('tranquility.png')
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(rgb_image)

# 3x3 mask
blurred_image3 = cv2.blur(bgr_image, (3, 3))
cv2.imwrite('blurred_image3.png', blurred_image3)

# 5x5 mask
blurred_image5 = cv2.blur(bgr_image, (5, 5))
cv2.imwrite('blurred_image5.png', blurred_image5)
```

Вот попытка написать его вручную:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

bgr_image = cv2.imread('tranquility.png', 0);
image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
width = image.shape[1]
height = image.shape[0]
result = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), dtype='uint8')


def meanFilter():
    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            currentElement = 0;
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            top = 0;
            bottom = 0;
            topLeft = 0;
            topRight = 0;
            bottomLeft = 0;
            bottomRight = 0;
            counter = 1
            currentElement = image[row][col]

            if not col - 1 < 0:
                left = image[row][col - 1]
                counter += 1
            if not col + 1 > width - 1:
                right = image[row][col + 1]
                counter += 1
            if not row - 1 < 0:
                top = image[row - 1][col]
                counter += 1
            if not row + 1 > height - 1:
                bottom = image[row + 1][col]
                counter += 1

            if not row - 1 < 0 and not col - 1 < 0:
                topLeft = image[row - 1][col - 1]
                counter += 1
            if not row - 1 < 0 and not col + 1 > width - 1:
                topRight = image[row - 1][col + 1]
                counter += 1
            if not row + 1 > height - 1 and not col - 1 < 0:
                bottomLeft = image[row + 1][col - 1]
                counter += 1
            if not row + 1 > height - 1 and not col + 1 > width - 1:
                bottomRight = image[row + 1][col + 1]
                counter += 1

            total = int(currentElement) + int(left) + int(right) + \
                    int(top) + int(bottom) + int(topLeft) + int(topRight) \
                    + int(bottomLeft) + int(bottomRight)
            avg = total / counter
            result[row][col] = avg


meanFilter();
cv2.imshow('Blurred', result);
cv2.imshow('Original', image);
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку и сделать так чтоб можно было изменять сетку 3х3 и т.д.
Код ошибки:

```
  File "D:/Files/Averaging Filter/averaging.py", line 53, in meanFilter
    topRight) + int(bottomLeft) + int(bottomRight)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Интересный подход. Если не секрет, зачем вообще такое делать? Быстрее чем в OpenCV у Вас вряд ли получится алгоритм, так зачем?

Comment: Лабораторная работа в университете.

Comment: int(currentElement) - так нельзя.  У Вас проблема с преобразованием типа. Нельзя ndarray в int переделать. Там вектороное значение. Есть атрибуты min, max - используйте их например.